# Chrome applying borders to below tr td's

Tags: css, google-chrome, drupal-7, calendar

[image: Calendar in Chrome]
[image: Calendar in Firefox]

My issue is that within Google Chrome the left and right borders (in the images above the .today styling is over-riding the left border) of a td are somehow cascading unto the td of a below tr (as seen above, 1st image). This doesn't occur in either Firefox (as seen above, 2nd image) or IE (identical to 2nd image). I can't find any reason as to why this is happening (obviously, else I wouldn't be here).

So I've got a calendar Table with three tr rows for each day; Date-box, Multi-day and Single-day. Like this:

```
| Date(Day1, tr1, td1) || Date(Day2, tr1, td2) |

| Single(Day1, tr2, td1, NoValue) || Multi(Day2, tr2, td2) |

| No-td || Single(Day2, tr3, td2) |

| Date(Day3, tr4, td1) || Date(Day4, tr4, td2) |

| Single(Day3, tr5, td1) || Single(Day4, tr5, td2) |

| Single(Day3, tr5, td1) || Single(Day4, tr5, td2) |
```

As demonstrated above if an event that is displayed within calendar either spans multiple days or spans an entire day a new tr called multi-day is created. Any days that have events in them but are only active during certain hours of the day (e.g. 2:30 to 5:30) appear in the multi day row but have the class of single-day. Any non-multi-day events that take place on the same day as a multi day event appear underneath the multi-day event on the single day tr. If there are no events on a multi day row then the single day tr contains no tds. If on a calendar week there are no multi day events then the single day tr takes the space of both rows.
The Multi day tds have this styling attached to them:

```
#block-system-main tr.multi-day td.multi-day{    
border: 1px solid #7C7F12;
border-left: 2px solid #7C7F12;
border-right: 2px solid #7C7F12;
}
```

The single day td's don't have this styling on them. The calendar is a drupal 7 Module with custom css on it. I've checked and double checked that all tags are closing correctly.  Considering this is only rendering like this within chrome and its custom css I see no reason for this bug to be Drupal related.

And finally if you really want to trough through the html here it is:

```
    <tr class="date-box">
      <td id="calendar-2014-02-09-date-box" class="date-box past" colspan="1" 
rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-09"  headers="Sunday"  data-day-of-month="9" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="month day"> 9 </div>  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-10-date-box" class="date-box past" colspan="1" 
rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-10"  headers="Monday"  data-day-of-month="10" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="month day"> 10 </div>  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-11-date-box" class="date-box past" colspan="1" 
rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-11"  headers="Tuesday"  data-day-of-month="11" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="month day"> 11 </div>  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-12-date-box" class="date-box past" colspan="1" 
rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-12"  headers="Wednesday"  data-day-of-month="12" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="month day"> 12 </div>  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-13-date-box" class="date-box today" colspan="1" 
rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-13"  headers="Thursday"  data-day-of-month="13" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="month day"> 13 </div>  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-14-date-box" class="date-box future" colspan="1" 
rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-14"  headers="Friday"  data-day-of-month="14" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="month day"> <a href="http://schools.websitedevelopment.ltd.uk/calendar-node-field-date/day/2014-02-14">14</a> </div>  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-15-date-box" class="date-box future" colspan="1" 
rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-15"  headers="Saturday"  data-day-of-month="15" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="month day"> 15 </div>  </div>
    </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="multi-day">
      <td id="calendar-2014-02-09-0" class="single-day no-entry past" colspan="1"
 rowspan="2" data-date="2014-02-09"  headers="Sunday"  data-day-of-month="9" >
      <div class="inner">
        &nbsp;  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-10-0" class="single-day no-entry past" colspan="1" 
rowspan="2" data-date="2014-02-10"  headers="Monday"  data-day-of-month="10" >
      <div class="inner">
        &nbsp;  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-11-0" class="single-day no-entry past" colspan="1" 
rowspan="2" data-date="2014-02-11"  headers="Tuesday"  data-day-of-month="11" >
      <div class="inner">
        &nbsp;  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-12-0" class="single-day no-entry past" colspan="1" 
rowspan="2" data-date="2014-02-12"  headers="Wednesday"  data-day-of-month="12" >
      <div class="inner">
        &nbsp;  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-13-0" class="single-day no-entry today" colspan="1" 
rowspan="2" data-date="2014-02-13"  headers="Thursday"  data-day-of-month="13" >
      <div class="inner">
        &nbsp;  </div>
    </td>
    <td class="multi-day" colspan="1" rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-14" >
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">
      <div class="view-item view-item-calendar">
      <div class="calendar monthview">
        <div style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#ffffff" class="stripe" title="Key: Event">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="calendar.91.field_date.0.0 contents">
                          <a href="/open-event">Open Event</a>                      
<span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2014-02-14T00:00:00+00:00">(All day)</span>          </div>  
            <div class="cutoff">&nbsp;</div>
          </div> 
      </div>   
    </div>  </div>
    </td>
    <td id="calendar-2014-02-15-0" class="single-day no-entry future" colspan="1" rowspan="2" data-date="2014-02-15"  headers="Saturday"  data-day-of-month="15" >
      <div class="inner">
        &nbsp;  </div>
    </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="single-day">
      <td id="calendar-2014-02-14-1" class="single-day no-entry noentry-multi-day 
future" colspan="1" rowspan="1" data-date="2014-02-14"  headers="Friday"  data-day-of-month="14" >
      <div class="inner">
        &nbsp;  </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

I would put more complete css code in as well but this is drupal, so there's just so much css fluff that's completely and utterly irrelevant to the site and specificity this problem.  The only bits that seem to be relevant is the css I've put in above.

Thanks for taking the time to read through this post.

EDIT I've tried re-creating the issue in a blank html file and have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: The CSS doesn't match the HTML. There is no `id="block-system-main"` in the HTML. Now I added a start tag for the table with that id, but it still doesn't cause any differences between Firefox and Chrome. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XH4ux/).

Comment: The above html is a snippet of the complete table, its only the one relevant week of the month (the one with the multi-day). EDIT In fact the 'block-system-main' id is of a containing div.